# how to move file in Nodejs if we have access to both its path and buffer?

Tags: node.js, file, express, upload, buffer

After sending a file to an Express server which uses `multer` middleware, we are given the file's path and a buffer to the file contents.

```
app.post('/api/createProduct', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  var path = req.file.path   // full path of uploaded file
  var buff = req.file.buffer // buffer of entire file
  // ... business logic
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

After some "business logic", we may want to move the file to a new location or delete it.

Having access to both the path and the buffer, what would be the most efficient way to either delete the file or move it to a new location? Is there any particular situation where access to the buffer is desirable?

Comment: I would suspect moving/"renaming" a file would be more efficient since at the filesystem level it typically is cheaper to do than to write out a whole new file and then deleting the old one.

Comment: Just use `fs.rename()` with old path and then a new path and that will move the file.